Error when setting up Google Remote Desktop on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I'm trying to set up google remote desktop from my Ubuntu system but I am getting the following error once I input the PIN number:

/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/0ATx3LY5GrVmzcbFPuQAdl7S9Ns5QFRbGGIO3RCwgobyuPbYyire9LBsu4D3NXyQ3YSFv6A" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)
Enter a PIN of at least six digits:
Enter the same PIN again:
[0711/141306.338922:ERROR:breakpad_utils.cc(127)] Failed to create minidump directory: /chromoting/minidumps
[0711/141306.642590:INFO:host_starter_base.cc(74)] 
  Found existing host: `7d21f528-9ab4-45ad-9ebb-c9ed58631137`.
  This instance will be deleted from the Directory before starting the new host instance.
[0711/141308.397440:INFO:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(98)] /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop:2526: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  re.split('\s+', os.environ[HOST_EXTRA_PARAMS_ENV_VAR].strip())
The daemon is not currently running

[0711/141315.028864:INFO:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(98)] /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop:2526: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  re.split('\s+', os.environ[HOST_EXTRA_PARAMS_ENV_VAR].strip())
Failed to start chrome-remote-desktop@slides-pr-6.service: Unit chrome-remote-desktop@slides-pr-6.service has a bad unit file setting.
See system logs and 'systemctl status chrome-remote-desktop@slides-pr-6.service' for details.```


That seems to be a bug with Google's software. Now, they are among the largest companies on this planet, I guess they should have an engineer that fixes their software if you report this as a bug. It doesn't seem to me you can do anything about this.

What is your python version?.  See SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence

My version is Python 3.12.2 Does this mean I should use raw strings instead?

Hey Gabriel, I am encountering the same problem. I am wondering if you have found a solution. Cheers.

Hey @echan see the answer for a possible solution that worked for me.

This is not a pleasant answer, but it appears that '-' dashes in the userid seem to have an effect on the SSH setup
Please try a user without dashes 'slides-pr-6' to maybe 'slidespr6'
I removed dashes and it did work in my case.
Not pleasant but possibly true.
